# Why in uniform space contains small sets should be nonempty meets?

Tags: general-topology

In the figure, $\delta(F)<V$ means $F\times F\subseteq V$. Wy $\bigcap\mathcal F\neq\varnothing$?
If we let $\mathcal F=\{\{x\},\{y\}\}$, then it clearly satisfies the condition: contains arbitrary small sets, but $\bigcap\mathcal F=\varnothing$ .[image]

Comment: "contains at most one point" means "contain zero point" (ie "is empty") OR "contains one point". So your example doesn't contradict the statement.

Comment: Is the projection operator $p_i$ from a product of uniform spaces to $X_i$ is a closed map? i.e., if $F\subseteq\Pi X_i$ is closed, then $p_i(F)$ is closed in $X_i$ induced by $\mathcal U_i$.